# Fixing the wrong encoding of filenames

Tags: locale, zip, unicode, encoding, filename

I have a Linode server running Ubuntu 22.04. When I log in through SSH and download files with "Sinhala" language in their names, they show up correctly in the terminal, and I can compress and extract them without any problems.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 26039231 Jul 30 14:57 'ශ්‍රී ලංකාවේ ජාතික වෘක්ෂය වන (නා) ගසේ ඔබ නොදත් වට්නා තොරතුරු.mp4'
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     4096 Sep  4 07:56 'Test folder'
```

But, after I updated the files and logged back into the server, it kinda ended up looking like this.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 26039231 Jul 30 14:57 '$'\340\267\201\340\267\212\342\200\215\340\266\273\340\267\223'' '$'\340\266\275\340\266\202\340\266\232\340\267\217\340\267\200\340\267\232'' '$'\340\266\242\340\267\217\340\266\255\340\267\222\340\266\232'' '$'\340\267\200\340\267\230\340\266\232\340\267\212\340\267\202\340\266\272'' '$'\340\267\200\340\266\261'' ('$'\340\266\261\340\267\217'') '$'\340\266\234\340\267\203\340\267\232'' '$'\340\266\224\340\266\266'' '$'\340\266\261\340\267\234\340\266\257\340\266\255\340\267\212'' '$'\340\267\200\340\266\247\340\267\212\340\266\261\340\267\217'' '$'\340\266\255\340\267\234\340\266\273\340\266\255\340\267\224\340\266\273\340\267\224''. [bUya0DMO2Ag].mp4
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     4096 Sep  4 07:56 'Test folder'
```

When I zip a file and open it on my Mac, it looks completely different and has a new set of weird characters. I've tried changing settings, running commands, and tweaking language settings, but it's still the same problem.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Comment: According to https://www.cogsci.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.cgi?input=e0+b7+81&mode=bytes, the byte sequence `\340\267\201` is SINHALA LETTER TAALUJA SAYANNA `ශ` which seems to be the first character of the file name according to my browser's search function. There might be different representations of the same character. Do you use the same `ls` command in both situations? Please [edit] your question and copy&paste the output of `locale` in both cases. Show the commands to compress and extract the files. How exactly did you *download* and *update* the files?

Comment: Mac? Then this confusion is probably related to the fact that Mac sets a `LC_CTYPE` value ("UTF-8") which is not a valid locale name in Ubuntu. To test that theory, can you please — as also suggested by @Bodo — edit your question and show us the output of this terminal command: `locale`